# First shifting property (Laplace transform)

Tags: laplace-transform

$$\mathcal{L}(e^{3t}\sin(5t)\sin(3t)) $$

I tried it. But I dont know the answer for this question. So I need to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathcal{L}(e^{3t}\sin(5t)\sin(3t))$$
$$f(t)=e^{3t}\sin(5t)\sin(3t)$$
Transform the product into a sum
$$\sin(5t)\sin(3t)=\frac12 ( \cos (2t)-\cos (8t))$$
So that we have:
$$f(t)=\frac 12e^{3t} \cos (2t)-\frac 12 e^{3t}\cos(8t)$$
$$\mathcal{L}(f(t))=\frac 12\mathcal{L}(e^{3t} \cos (2t))-\frac 12 \mathcal{L}(e^{3t}\cos(8t))$$
Apply the following formula:
$$\mathcal{L}(e^{bt} \cos (at))=\dfrac {(s-b)}{(s-b)^2+a^2}$$